# String of cursor.execute without executing

Tags: python, mysql, sql, pymysql

I am using the following approach to using `pymysql` to parametrize the SQL+args query but not execute it (legitimately, at least):

```
try:
    self.cursor.execute(self.sql + ' ***', self.sql_args or tuple())    
except pymysql.err.ProgrammingError:                                      
    self._sql_formatted = self.cursor._last_executed.rstrip('* ')
```

Is there actually a method that `pymysql` has where it just formats the SQL string without executing it, or do I need to use something like the above? Or, another option:

```
self.cursor.execute('DESCRIBE ' + self.sql, self.sql_args or tuple())
self._sql_formatted = self.cursor._last_executed.replace('DESCRIBE ', '')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [cursor.mogrify](https://pymysql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/cursors.html#pymysql.cursors.Cursor.mogrify) method

> Returns the exact string that is sent to the database by calling the execute() method.

```
>>> conn = pymysql.connect(host='localhost', user='root', password='password', database='test')
>>> cur = conn.cursor()
>>> stmt1 = """SELECT id, password FROM my_user WHERE name = %s;"""
>>> print(cur.mogrify(stmt1, ('Alice',)))
SELECT id, password FROM my_user WHERE name = 'Alice';
```

Comment: I'd guess that it's a back-formation from "transmogrify", wich is a [jocular] word meaning "transform".